# Unable to receive server data in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsurlsession

I want to receive data from server. But the value of data is getting nil. 
The code is giving below.

```
- (void) EstablishNetworkConnectionThread:(NSString *) url{
@try {
    url=[url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSString * API = url;
    //NSLog(@"NetworkConnection = %@", API);
    NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@""];
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    //NSURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:API]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    [request setHTTPBody:postData];
    [request setTimeoutInterval:60.0];

    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSData *POSTReply = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:nil];
    NSString *theReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[POSTReply bytes] length:[POSTReply length] encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    NSError *e = [[NSError alloc] init];
    dictJSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: [theReply dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &e];
    NSLog(@"NetworkConnection JSON = %@", dictJSON);

    if (dictJSON == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Web Service Error url = %@\nError = %@", url, theReply);
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(PopUpNetworkMessage) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
    }


    [[LoadingViewController instance] stopRotation];
} @catch (NSException *exception) {
    [[LoadingViewController instance] stopRotation];
} @finally { }
}
```

dictJSON is an ivar and the value of dictJSON is getting nil. 
what is the solution???

Comment: Log `e` and you'll know why `dictJSON` is `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
        NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                                completionHandler:
                                      ^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *connectionError) {
                                          // ...
                                          }];


        [task resume];
```

use NSURLSession to get response ,NSURLConnection is Deprecated on ios9.0.

Answer (score 0):

1. This is a bad idea:

   ```
   url=[url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
   ```

   Don't do that.  IMO, stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: should be deprecated, if not removed outright.  It is fundamentally unsafe for any purposes.  There is exactly one safe way to add percent escapes, and that is to do so one component at a time, as you're building up the URL string.  And if you have a valid URL to begin with, this is likely to make it invalid.
2. Your post data is always empty.  Why are you doing that at all?
3. I don't think you actually have to set Content-Length when you provide a body with an NSData object.
4. Never use sendSynchronousRequest.  Synchronous network requests are seriously problematic, and not just because they block the thread on which they're running.
5. Is this compiled with ARC?  If not, then you'll need to retain when you store data into the ivar.  Otherwise, it will end up being empty when you go back to check its value later.
6. Why are you converting the response from an NSData object to an NSString (lossily) and then back to an NSData object?  Just pass the NSData object to NSJSONSerialization, unless you're trying to work around bugs in that API or something.

It's hard to say which, if any, of the above is causing your problem, though.  The first thing I would do, if fixing the above issues doesn't help, is to check the server logs, and if possible, sniff the network traffic with tcpdump/wireshark to see what's actually being sent and received.